# How to use function currying in Swift 4

Tags: swift, currying

I try to understand the [function currying tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introduction-to-function-currying-in-swift) but that code seem out of date. And it's still not really clear about function currying.

I try with this function:

```
 func curry<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping (A, B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B) -> C {
    return { a in { b in f(a, b)} }
}
```

And it runs ok with `Playground (Xcode 9 beta 6)`. But the problem is I cannot use this function as the tutorial:

```
let add = curry(+)
let xs = 1...100
let x = xs.map(add(2))
```

The code above return error:

```
Playground execution failed:

    error: FunctionsCurrying.playground:31:17: error: ambiguous use of operator '+'
    let add = curry(+)
                    ^
```

Please correct me and help me to clear about `function currying`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That problem is not Swift 4 related, you would get the same error
message in Swift 3.

There are many overloaded `+` operators, therefore in

```
let add = curry(+)
```

the compiler does not know which one to choose. With an explicit type
cast

```
let add = curry((+) as ((Int, Int) -> Int))
```

or an explicit type annotation

```
let op: (Int, Int) -> Int = (+)
let add = curry(op)
```

the code compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: It's worked. But still got confused that why operator `+` can casts to function `((Int, Int) -> Int)`. Could you explain at this point?

Comment: @lee: As I said, there are many overloaded + operators, they differ in the types of the parameters, e.g. `(Int, Int) -> Int` and `(Double, Double) -> Double` and many more. With `as ...` you tell the compiler which one to choose to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: ooh, got it. Thanks so much for your help.